# errors for each layer in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I am trying to visualize the errors of each layer in CNN by tensor-board with Keras to see how they change in every layer timely. How do I get errors for each layer?

Comment: I have seen a losses property in layer class and there is a function called "get_losses_for". Are these can be used to get the value which i want?

Answer (score 0):

The loss is defined only in the output layer to measure how good your model fits the data. keras provides a function to keep track of relevant variables during the training process called History().

```
from keras.callbacks import History

history = History()

# define and compile your model
model.fit(..., callbacks=[history])
print(history.history)
```

The last command shows you all tracked values during the training process. You can access single variables via the get() method. To get the training loss, you can access it via

```
history.history.get('loss')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I would like the loss values for each layer in a model, because I want to use the changes of these loss values to evaluate networks on training phase.

Comment: As I stated above, the loss is not defined for any other layer than the output layer. Do you mean the error terms that are backpropagated during the training process? If not, please elaborate more on the kind of values you are interested in.

Comment: Sorry for my wrong expression, the error terms that you mentioned is exactly what i want. Could you tell me how to get them?